# A sequence of Push Segues in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have a sequence of `UIViewControllers`. The initial view in the application is a `UINavigationController` with a `UIViewController` as the rootviewcontroller.

There are push segues from each of the view controllers in a sequence like so:

```
UINV ----> RVC --Push1--> VC1 --Push2--> VC2 --Push3--> VC3
```

Where UINV is the `UINavigationController`, RVC is the `RootViewController`, and VC1,2,3 are the `UIViewControllers`.

Push1 Segue works just fine. Push2 Segue gives me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Any clue what is wrong here? I need this sequence so I can go back and forth between the pages using the UINavigationItem buttons (back and next).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I solved this issue. The EXC_BAD_ACCESS was due to another issue.

What had happened was that I had a Container View in VC2. The embed segue in the storyboard had accidentally pointed to itself instead of another View Controller which was to be embedded as a child view controller. This was causing the crash.

I'll just leave it here in case somebody discovers the problem.

Do not mess with the embed segue link in storyboard.